# Current date without datetime pymongo

Tags: python, date, datetime, pymongo

I need to return the current date without using `datetime` in pymongo to replace:

```
datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

I am implementing an interface and if I use `datetime`, it returns me the date of creation (because it will run only once) and not the date of the day.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean the code is invoked only once at startup and that's why you get the date when the datetime instance was created?
If that's the case, it won't change if you use another method, you need invoke the method to get the current date when the request is made.

Comment: Are you looking for `datetime.date.today()`?

Comment: @Bernhard, yes exactly. I'm a begineer so I'm asking how to do a live function that generates the date each time that I invoke the UI.

Comment: @matino, no I'm currently using datetime.date.today() which seems to be a static function. And because I'm using it in a UI, it will never take the date of launching of the UI and nevers change it

Comment: Can you show more of your code so that we can see where the datetime objectd is instantiated and how you use it with pymongo?

Comment: DEFINED_PARAMETERS = {'last_day' : {'production': {'job_create_date': {'$gt': datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=10)}                       Re = Reporter(DEFINED_REPORTS['last_day'])
report = Re.run_report()
json = write_file("test_report.json", report)

Comment: But after, these reports will be available on an interface invokes once and so the datetime will not work anymore

Comment: Perhaps you should use some persistent storage?